# Default toleration on pods with resource limits/requests

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Hej there,

Recently I discovered that some pods in my k8s cluster have the following toleration:
`node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule`

I thought it was odd that this toleration exists on common pods so I experimented and ensured that my thought is correct; that these pods will be scheduled on nodes with the taint of the same name.
That doesn't make sense at all.

I have additional tolerations, such as

- `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s`
- `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s`

But these make sense. I can't figure out why I have the toleration `node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule` so I'm wondering if somebody could guide me in the correct direction.

Of course I checked the Deployment and ReplicaSets and ReplicationControllers, but don't know where else I could have a look. The unitfile looks fine and the kubelet configs seems normal as well.

Some facts:

- k8s version: 1.20.0
- k8s flavor: OpenShift

Update:

- When I create a new deploymentconfig, the created pod doesn't have the `memory-pressure` toleration.
- There are also initContainers. The pods created through them don;t have the `memory-pressure` toleration either

Update2:
I played with the DeploymentConfig I've got and the toleration for `memory-pressure` is added when I either define resource memory limit, request or both.
That seems odd to me and I can not reproduce this on a k3s cluster.

Comment: From [OpenShift Documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/nodes/scheduling/nodes-scheduler-taints-tolerations.html#nodes-scheduler-taints-tolerations-about-taintBasedEvictions_nodes-scheduler-taints-tolerations): "OpenShift Container Platform automatically adds a toleration for `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready` and `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable` with `tolerationSeconds=300`, unless the Pod configuration specifies either toleration." It seems you are using some custom resource, which is added `node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule` to all pods automatically.

Comment: I do realize that but I wonder how it's possible to understand what resource in particular does this.

Comment: You can check namespace toleration. [Article](https://zhimin-wen.medium.com/default-toleration-at-namespace-level-f66dd3da4451) about it. Also [information about project toleration](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/taints-expectations-vs.-reality).